# Sublime Text / Spyder / Text-antialiasing Windows

Tags: windows, ide, sublimetext, antialiasing, spyder

In a nutshell, I can't get text in Spyder to look nearly as good as Sublime Text. (I have the same basic problem with PyCharm in comparison to Sublime, as well).

Below is a pic of the same file (Sublime left, Spyder right), side by side in both programs, same font (Source Code Pro, 13 points), both running Monokai Extended Bright, which I went in and tweaked a little to get the colors to match as much as possible.  ClearType is on.

Is there anything that can be done to make text - pardon the pun - more Sublime?  Some programs seem to have good font rendering (Sublime, Cmder/Conemu with cmd.exe), others not so much.  It's clearly possible to make the text look good on Windows, is there anything that can be done from a user-level to fix it?

[image: Screen Shot Comparing Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from running through the entire Clear Type setup again (which I'd recommend doing, it helped me out a lot recently), there's not much you can do to modify how individual programs render text. Some Windows programs tie in to the Windows libraries for rendering text and graphics (and I believe there are a number to choose from, as well as different versions, so performance among them may vary considerably depending on your hardware and software), while others either take advantage of third-party libraries or, like Sublime, roll their own. The general consensus online from people who should know is that Jon Skinner, the creator of Sublime Text, wrote his own GUI library in C++, one of the reasons for Sublime's small size and speed - only the functions that are needed are there, not the whole kitchen sink. Notes in the [various](http://www.sublimetext.com/dev) [dev builds](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) indicate that he's tweaked it quite a bit, so I would imagine the performance is just getting better. PyCharm's authors likely don't have Skinner's level of obsession with font rendering, and their graphics engine may not have that level of tuning capability at any rate.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if he wrote his text-display routines then or just used the Windows ones correctly?  I find the text output from Cmder (which is a modified ConEmu, running cmd.exe with mysgit) to be just about as good as Sublime, and far better than plain cmd.exe.  Frustrating to know it's possible but generally ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with pycharm;

settings/editor/appearance, and check the 'use anti-aliased fonts' box. 
something I remember about source code pro on windows, TTF files were smoother than OTF ones.

Comment: Even with anti-aliasing PyCharm still doesn't seem to render as smoothly (IIRC) as Sublime.  I haven't tried TTF vs. OTF, I was always under the impression OTF was the better format where available?

Comment: have you tried to tune cleartype text settings from Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Adjust CleaType text

Comment: Yes.  The Sublime example renders what I consider essentially perfectly, as do things like Cmder, so it's not a system-level issue - I know Chrome rendered text poorly on Windows for a while.