# Make Spyder IDE have dark background and colored syntax highlighting

Tags: user-interface, syntax, spyder, appearance

My question is simple, but I couldn't manage to do it on my own, how can I make Spyder (on Ubuntu) look like Sublime Text? 
I see this guy managed it :

[Sublime Text / Spyder / Text-antialiasing Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049580/sublime-text-spyder-text-antialiasing-windows)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

in spyder go to tools-->preferences... Once in preferences, on the left side of the windows go to where it says editor. once in editor, in the display tab scroll all the way down to where it says "Syntax color scheme", click and choose the one that says "Spyder/Dark..... click apply and ok.... That should be all you need. also to make it look closer to sublime just drag the console to the horizontal bottom and close the variable explorer window.